# тип загружаемых данных

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, dataframe

столкнулся с такой проблемой.
загружаю данные из Excel (выписка по банковскому счету).
есть полтора десятка столбцов, часть из которых нужно обрабатывать, как числа, часть, как объекты.
среди столбцов есть числовые (ИНН, БИК банка), которые полностью состоят из цифр, но нужно сохранять и обрабатывать как строки, т.к. они могут начинаться с 0 и этот знак важен.

в файле Excel, из которого я все беру - все отображается красиво и правильно (БИК и ИНН в файле Excel изначально записаны не как числа, а как строки).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но когда я читаю все в pandas происходит следующее.
БИК читается как число и если первым знаком идет 0, он сразу отбрасывается.
а ИНН вообще читается, как число в виде экспоненциальной записи (7.****e+09)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот код

```
account_stateman = pd.read_excel('C:/file.xlsx', sheet_name='New_Account_Stateman')
```

как сделать так, чтобы нужные мне столбцы считывались не как числа, а как строки?

Comment: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7060/217579)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь параметром [dtype](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html):

```
account_stateman = pd.read_excel('C:/file.xlsx', 
                                 sheet_name='New_Account_Stateman', 
                                 dtype={'BIK':str, 'INN':str})
```

Comment: спасибо. все получилось